# Display utf8 coding when using fontspec package

Tags: fonts

I wonder that how can I display true character in utf8 with using fontspec package. 
Here is my example

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Agency FB} 
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam} 
\begin{document} 
   Chế độ hoạt động 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use the vietnam package with xelatex. Beside this: Your font doesn't contain the glyphs and so is imho not suited for this language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the problems with Agency FB that Vietnamese language is not supported so much, so I use modify fonts named SVN-Agency FB written by Ken Nguyễn, it's display ok like other fonts such as Arial, TimeNewRomans,...
My code is like above but remove this line `\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}`, running with XeLaTex.
Here is it

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{SVN-Agency FB}  
\begin{document} 
  Chế độ hoạt động 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As Ulrike Fischer says you need a font that includes these characters.  On a Mac there is, for example, Lucida Grande. Also to set vietnamese you can use the `polyglossia` package:

[image: Sample output]

```
% xelatex
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{LucidaGrande} 

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{vietnamese}

\begin{document} 

Chế độ hoạt động 

\end{document}
```